# нагрузка на CPU из-за потоков в dll c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, dll

есть такого типа код:

```
bool isActive = false;

DWORD WINAPI Hack_Thread(LPVOID);

DWORD WINAPI Hack_Thread(LPVOID)
{
    while (1) 
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
        {
            MessageBox(0,L"123456",L"654321", MB_OK);
        }
    return 1;
    }
}

DWORD APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, Hack_Thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

все работает норм,длл-ка инжектится,но в Proccess Explorer ужасная нагрузка на проц,а приложение крушится после 5-10 минут работы.я новичок в с++,но как я понимаю,происходят бесконечные потоки.как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как правильно [заметил VTT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908060/208074), в `DllMain()` нельзя создавать потоки.

Однако ничто не мешает вам отсрочить выполнение своего кода средствами kernel32.dll. Так как у нас нет документированного доступа к loader lock (мьютексу загрузчика модулей), мы не можем определить окончание запрета на создание потоков, а потому вынуждены использовать таймер с достаточно большой задержкой (например, 500 мс).

Так как использовать user32.dll тоже нельзя, таймер у нас будет ядерный:

```
static HANDLE hTimer;

static VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    // Наша полезная нагрузка, вынесенная из DllMain
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, Hack_Thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Удаляем объект таймера
    DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, hTimer, NULL);
}

DWORD APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateTimerQueueTimer(&hTimer, NULL, TimerCallback, NULL, 500, 0,
                               WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Флаг `WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD` нужен, чтобы наша функция `TimerCallback()` исполнялась в том же потоке, откуда была вызвана `DllMain`. Это необязательно, но раз нам всё равно не нужна параллельность (мы не выполняем вычисления, а просто создаём свой постоянный поток), то нет никакой необходимости неявно создавать для неё ещё потоки, подконтрольные не нам, а системе.

Comment: благодарю,попробую)

Answer (score 1):

Среди [того, что нельзя делать в dll main](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices):

> вызывать `CreateThread`

Это можно решить отказавшись от внедрения dll

`GetAsyncKeyState` кстати тоже не будет нормально работать

Comment: без внедрения я не смогу управлять приложением,суть такова что я внедряюсь ,узнаю дескриптор сокета и шлю пакеты по нажатию клавиш.разве можно в моем случае отказаться?